# mongodb - retrieve multiple documents efficiently

Tags: mongodb, performance, pymongo

I want to download ~100K records from mongodb.
Using pymongo.
find() returns cursor, which, i guess, go to the db (cloud) for each single doc. This takes ~0.003 per document, not so good.
Is there some way to perform "fetch all" or something like that, to reduce run time?

Comment: *find() returns cursor, which, i guess, go to the db (cloud) for each single doc* - why that? it'll return a resultset at once

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest cursor should go to the db each step. am i wrong?

Comment: @mclafee how about using `mongoexport`? You can specify a query so that you can select which documents you want exported.